# Server side clusters of coordinates based on zoom level

Tags: python, google-maps, postgresql, google-maps-markers, cluster-analysis

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986852/clustering-coordinates-on-server-side/995876#995876)  I managed to come up with a temporary solution to my problem.

However, with a list of 6000 points that grows everyday it's becoming slower and slower.

I can't use a third party service* therefore I need to come up with my own solution.

Here are my requirements:

1. Clustering of the coordinates need
   to work with any zoom level of the
   map.
2. All clusters need to be cached
3. Ideally there won't be a need to
   cluster (calculate distances) on all
   points if a new point is added.

So far I have implemented quadtree that returns the four boundaries of my map and returns whatever coordinates are within the viewable section of the map.

What I need and I know this isn't easy is to have clusters of the points returned from the DB (postgres).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am currently doing dynamic server-side clustering of about 2,000 markers, but it runs pretty quick up to 20,000.  You can see discussion of my algorithm here:

[Map Clustering Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434222/)

Whenever the user moves the map I send a request with the zoom level and the boundaries of the view to the server, which clusters the viewable markers and sends it back to the client.

I don't cache the clusters because the markers can be dynamically filtered and searched - but if they were pre-clustered it would be super fast!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you have to "cluster" on the fly. Summarize at each zoom level at a resolution you're happy with.

Simply have a structure of X, Y, # of links. When someone adds a link, you insert the real locations (Zoom level max, or whatever), then start bubbling up from there.

Eventually you'll have 10 sets of distinct coordinates if you have 10 zoom levels - one for each different zoom level.

The calculation is trivial, and you only have to do it once.

Comment: What if on zoom level 1 you can have 500 markers, and on level 2 5000 markers?